# Is fourier transform of $C_0^\infty (\mathbb R)$ dense in $L_\mathbb C ^1 (\mathbb R) \cap L_\mathbb C ^2(\mathbb R) $?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $C_0^\infty (\mathbb R)$ be space of smooth functions with compact support on the real line. 
Let  $L_\mathbb C ^1 (\mathbb R) \cap L_\mathbb C ^2(\mathbb R) $ be equivalence class of 1-fold and 2-fold integrable functions. 
Let $\mathcal F$ denote fourier transformation.

I know $\mathcal F(C_0^\infty) \subseteq L_\mathbb C ^1 (\mathbb R) \cap L_\mathbb C ^2(\mathbb R) $  holds, but is it true that $$\mathcal F(C_0^\infty)=L_\mathbb C ^1 (\mathbb R) \cap L_\mathbb C ^2(\mathbb R) $$ ?

If not true then, is $F(C_0^\infty)$ dense in $L_\mathbb C ^1 (\mathbb R) \cap L_\mathbb C ^2(\mathbb R) $ ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: fourier transform is isometery on the shcwartz class or, by density and extension argument, on the space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. So the image is close. It is also dense. Hence the image will be the all space.

For the density use the following duallity fact.

$\mathscr{F}(F(-x))=f(w)$. Where 
$ F(w)= \mathscr{F}(f(x))$.

See the following nice book. The first pages of Chapter 2 answers your question very well.

Fourier Series and Integrals (H. Dym and H. P. McKean)

Comment: What does density mean? I'm very new at this topic.

Comment: @izimath For $f \in L^2$, if $\varphi,\phi \in C^\infty_c$ then $\varphi \ast f(x) \in C^\infty$ (convolution) and $\phi(x)  \ ( \varphi \ast f(x)) \in C^\infty_c$. Can you describe suitable $\varphi,\phi$ such that $\phi(x)  \ ( \varphi \ast f(x))$ is a good approximation of $f$ in $L^2$ norm ?

Comment: @reuns cutoff function for $\phi$ and the "looking like delta" function(Mollifiers?) for $\varphi$? I forgot the name

Comment: @izimath Yes we need an approximate identity for convolution and an approximate identity for product. Do you know how to construct those from a $C^\infty_c$ function like $\psi(x) = e^{-1/(1-x^2)} 1_{|x| < 1}$ ?

Comment: @reuns I do know how to construct a cutoff function. For the mollifier, maybe $\frac{1}{\varepsilon} \psi (x/\varepsilon)$?

Comment: Yes but don't forget the normalization constant $\frac{1}{\|\psi\|_{L^1}}$. Note if $f$ is continuous then it is easy to prove $\| f - f \ast \psi_\epsilon \|_{L^2} \to 0$ where $\psi_\epsilon(x) =\frac{1}{\varepsilon \|\psi\|_{L^1}} \psi (x/\varepsilon)$. If $f$ is not continuous, you need to show that $\|f-f_n\|_{L^2 }\to 0$ for some sequence of continuous functions $f_n$.  And note $\phi_\epsilon(x) = \psi(\epsilon x)$ works fine as an approximate ideantity for product. @izimath